# Make new One2many record through Wizard Odoo

Tags: python, odoo

I want to ask that how can I able to create One2many records through my wizard? Like I have a parent class A. On that form I have Created a One2many field. A button is placed(on parent form) to open up a wizard. The wizard has some selection fields. Now when I set the selection fields and click button (on wizard), I want to have all the result of my filtered records created on the One2many on the parent form. I have no idea how to get this done. My values are returning from wizard to parent form (simple fields) but I don't know how to get this done when dealing with One2many fields. Below is my parent class with the One2many relation class:

```
from openerp import models, fields, api
import openerp.exceptions

class hr_winter_module(models.Model):
    _name = "hr.winter.module"
    eligible_winter_ids = fields.One2many('hr.employee.winter.module', 'hr_winter_module_id', 'For Employee')
    set_amount = fields.Float('VALUE')
    my_name = fields.Char('NAME')
    my_job = fields.Char('JOB')
    my_country = fields.Char('COUNTRY')
    proposal_date = fields.Date('Date of Proposal', required=True, default=fields.Date.today() )
    _rec_name="proposal_date"


class hr_employee_winter_module(models.Model):

    _name='hr.employee.winter.module'

    @api.onchange('emp_name')
    @api.depends('emp_name')
    def myempl_name(self):
        for myrec in self:
            contract_records = myrec.env['hr.contract'].search([('employee_id','=', myrec.emp_name.id),('date_start','<=',fields.Date.today()),'|',('date_end','=',False),('date_end','>=',fields.Date.today())])
            stable=False
            if contract_records:
                stable = contract_records[-1:].analytic_account_id.name
            myrec.emp_stable= stable


    hr_winter_module_id = fields.Many2one("hr.winter.module", "Employee", ondelete="cascade")
    win_emp_name = fields.Many2one('hr.employee', string='Employee Name')
    win_zeo_number = fields.Char(related='win_emp_name.zeo_number', string='ZEO Number', readonly=True )
```

This is my wizard code :

```
from openerp import models, fields, api
import openerp.exceptions

class wizard_model(models.TransientModel):
    _name = "wizard.model"

    employee_type = fields.Selection([('muslim','Muslim'),('non-muslim','Non-Muslim'),('all','All')], default='all')
    stable_id = fields.Many2many('account.analytic.account', 'employee_stable', 'id', 'analytic_account_id', 'Stables', domain=[('parent_id','=','Stables') ])
    amount_for_all = fields.Float('Amount')
    emp_name = fields.Char('Enter Name')
    emp_job = fields.Char('Enter Job')
    emp_country = fields.Char('Enter Nationalty')
    @api.one
    def set_val(self):
        ids=self._ids
        cr = self._cr
        uid = self._uid
        context = self._context
        model_name=context.get('active_model')
        form_id = context.get('active_id')
        obj = self.pool.get(model_name).browse(cr,uid,form_id,context)

        obj.set_amount=self.amount_for_all
        obj.my_name = self.emp_name
        obj.my_job = self.emp_job
        obj.my_country = self.emp_country                  
        self.pool.get('hr.winter.module').write(cr, uid, ids, {'eligible_winter_ids':[ (0, 0, {'win_emp_name':self.emp_name})]})
```

Comment: Check in [this link](https://www.odoo.com/fr_FR/forum/help-1/question/hide-menu-for-existing-group-18704) the operations you can make in a many2many/one2many field

Answer (score 2):

To create records into an one2many field, simply pass a list of tuple **[(0,0,{'field1':value, 'field2':value, ...})]** to the one2many field in the parent class write method ,
 eg: self.write( cr, uid, ids, {'one2many_field_name':[ (0, 0, {'field':value}) ] })

Comment: I tried this     self.pool.get('hr.winter.module').write(cr, uid, ids, {'eligible_winter_ids':[ (0, 0, {'win_emp_name':self.emp_name})]})                       But it gives error :One of the records you are trying to modify has already been deleted (Document type: hr.winter.module).

Comment: the above error comes, when you are accessing one model with other model IDS. can you post your code.

Comment: here, the problem is while using write method, you are passing the IDS of wizard object. So, instead of passing IDS, the parent object IDS will be found in context. Once print context and see, it will be present as active_id attribute. So use context.get('active_id') in place of IDS

Comment: I see you are fetching context.get('active_id') in form_id. So, simply use form_id and check
self.pool.get('hr.winter.module').write(cr, uid, form_id, {'eligible_winter_ids':[ (0, 0, {'win_emp_name':self.emp_name})]})

Comment: what issue you are facing.

Comment: I m getting following error : DataError: invalid input syntax for integer: "adas"
LINE 1: ...nextval('hr_employee_winter_module_id_seq'), 138, 'adas', 1,...